# ошибка в изменении значения в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, post, update

Делаю сайт для поиска посылок. Все готово, но надо сделать страницу админки, где можно будет изменять статус посылки. Частично я уже сделал: выводятся все трек-коды в виде ссылок и выводится их текущий статус, но запись не изменяется и статус не выводится, хотя используется тот же метод, что и на главной странице админки. На странице админки все работает. Хочу сказать сразу, проблема не в соединении с БД! Буду очень рад если вы мне поможете и ответите.

```php
$key = $_POST['key'] ; 
$text = $_POST['status'] ;
echo "стаус трек кода ";
echo $key ;
echo " Успешно изменен на: ";
echo $text;
   $edit  = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE post SET `status`= `$text` WHERE `track` = `$key`");
   $status = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `track` = '$key'");
   $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($status);
  echo " Текущий статус: ";
  echo $result['status'];
```

Comment: Не те кавычки обрамляют литералы в первом запросе.

Comment: @Akina те, почему не те? В двойных переменная считывается

Comment: Возьмите запросы выведите в переменные, и выведите их на экран, может данные не приходят.

Comment: 1. Почему после выполнения запроса вы не проверяете на возможные  ошибки. Во всех примерах применения функции http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php присутствует обработка ошибок. Если делать как там рекомендуют то можно быстро понять что идет не так. 2. Почему вы заключаете $text и $key в обратные апострофы, а не в прямые одинарные или двойные кавычки. В MySQL в обратных апострофах могут быть только названия объектов БД (таблиц, колонок).

Comment: @Mike я пробовал, данные приходят, пробовал в разных кавычках и все прочее

Comment: @Akina я пробовал, но ничего

Comment: Что вы пробовали ? Самое главное поставить обработку ошибок. проверить статус завершения и если он false обязательно распечатать на экран сообщение об ошибке, которое вернула БД. Без адекватных сообщений об ошибках понять суть проблемы не возможно.

Comment: @Mike а как тут можно проверить что вернула бд?

Comment: Я же вам ссылку дал. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php посмотрите там в примерах как используется mysqli_query как проверяется и потом печатается $mysqli->error

Comment: *я пробовал, но ничего* Не верю. Ещё раз - строка кода должна выглядеть так: `$edit  = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE post SET \`status\`= '$text' WHERE \`track\` = '$key'");` - т.е. бэктики вокруг подставляемых литералов следует заменить на одинарные кавычки (как это правильно сделано в следующей строке кода), иначе подставляемые значения $text и $key интерпретируются не как строковые литералы, а как имена полей таблицы.

Comment: @Akina сделал все так как у вас, но без успешно и вот еще что, не выводиться текущий статус посылки из бд, если вам это поможет

Comment: нашел в чем ошибка @Mike просто url не передает такие запросы как key и status если поможите из предыдущей формы отправить пример как сделать так чтобы отправлялся тот статус который впишется в поле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Общем ошибка оказалась самая простая на предыдущей форме из который я получал статус надо было в форме вместо post поставить get и все сразу пропало, url передает все значения и все изменяется так что если у кого-то такая же ситуация то советую вместо переменных вставить определенные символы например вот так $key = "123" и точно так же со всем остальным и если значение изменилось то все значит ищите проблему на другой странице